# What is the problem of the sidebar and how to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make sidebar with `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` binding and if I move my mouse slower everything works fine, but if I go faster with my mouse the sidebar starts to move back and forth without stopping. Is there a way to fix it?

(Im new with tkinter and python in general)
[1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lZWL.png)
[2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwky7.png)

```
from tkinter import *

#MainWindow
def MainWindow():
    global WindowMain

    WindowMain = Tk()
    WindowMain.config(background="LightGray")
    WindowMain.overrideredirect(1)


#MainWindow_size
def Screen_size():
    app_width = 1280
    app_height = 720

    screen_width = WindowMain.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = WindowMain.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    WindowMain.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

#Func1
def close(e):
    for x in range(1000, 1200):
        Blue.place(x=x, y=0)
        DarkBlue.place(x=x, y=0)
        Blue.update()
        DarkBlue.update()
        Blue.bind("<Enter>", open)

#Func2
def open(e):
    for x in range(-1200, -1000):
        Blue.place(x=-x, y=0)
        DarkBlue.place(x=-x, y=0)
        Blue.update()
        DarkBlue.update()
        Blue.bind("<Leave>", close)


MainWindow()
Screen_size()

#Label1&2
Blue = Label(WindowMain, background="DeepSkyBlue",
             width=70, height=50)
DarkBlue = Label(WindowMain, width=2, height=100,
                 background="DodgerBlue")

Blue.place(x=1200)
DarkBlue.place(x=1200)

#Buttons
Quit = Button(WindowMain, text="Quit", command=quit,
              background="LightSkyBlue").pack()

Move = Button(WindowMain, text="open", command=open,
              background="LightSkyBlue", state=DISABLED).pack()
Undo = Button(WindowMain, text="close", command=close,
              background="LightSkyBlue", state=DISABLED).pack()


Blue.bind("<Enter>", open)


WindowMain.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you please post the code? We need to see the code to be able to help

Comment: you can click on the photo links to see it

Comment: Please include code in body of question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: If you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  It says: Do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Take a look into `after` method and avoid using loops and `update`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved.

- I just play around with `Blue.update()` and `Blue.bind`. See line
  31-31 and 40-41.
- In line 31-31 and 40-41, should be outside of looping.
- Do not used keyword `open` and `close`. Those are valid  for Python 3

Modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
#MainWindow
#def MainWindow():
    #global WindowMain

WindowMain = Tk()
WindowMain.config(background="LightGray")
#WindowMain.overrideredirect(1)


#MainWindow_size
def Screen_size():
    app_width = 1280
    app_height = 720

    screen_width = WindowMain.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = WindowMain.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    WindowMain.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

#Func1
def _close(e):
    for x in range(1000, 1200):
        Blue.place(x=x, y=0)
        DarkBlue.place(x=x, y=0)         
         
    Blue.update()    
    Blue.bind("<Enter>", _open)

#Func2
def _open(e):
    for x in range(-1200, -1000):
        Blue.place(x=-x, y=0)
        DarkBlue.place(x=-x, y=0)
                 
    Blue.update() 
    Blue.bind("<Leave>", _close)

Screen_size() 

#Label1&2
Blue = Label(WindowMain, background="DeepSkyBlue",
             width=70, height=50)
DarkBlue = Label(WindowMain,width=2, height=100,
                 background="DodgerBlue")

Blue.place(x=1200)
DarkBlue.place(x=1200)
 
#Buttons
Quit = Button(WindowMain, text="Quit", command=quit,
              background="LightSkyBlue").pack()

Move = Button(WindowMain, text="open", command=_open,
              background="LightSkyBlue", state=DISABLED).pack()
Undo = Button(WindowMain, text="close", command=_close,
              background="LightSkyBlue", state=DISABLED).pack()
  
Blue.bind("<Enter>", _open)
     
WindowMain.mainloop()
```

Screenshot before mouse moved:

[image]

Screenshot After mouse moved:

[image]